# TREE(3) and the Goodstein sequence

Tags: trees, ordinals, fixed-point-theorems, big-numbers, transfinite-recursion

[TREE(3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_tree_theorem) is an extremely large number that requires ordinal arithmetic to prove it is finite.  For what value of n would $G(n)>TREE(3)$?  The length of the
[Goodstein sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem) $G(n)$ is how many numbers in the sequence beginning with n are traversed in reaching 0. Proving that $G(n)$ is finite for all n also requires ordinal arithmetic and I'm more familiar with the Goodstein sequence.

For $n\ge8$, an $\omega^{\omega+1}$ sequence of decreasing ordinals is required to describe the Goodstein sequence and $G(12)$ is greater than Graham's number. For $G(16)$; $n\ge16$ a sequence beginning with $\omega^{\omega^\omega}$ iteration is required, and numbers that large are difficult to imagine even in terms of Graham's number type iterations.  $G(65536)$ requires $\omega\uparrow\uparrow 4$ iteration.

***How large a value of n would be required*** so that
$G(2\uparrow\uparrow n)>TREE(3)$?  I chose the $2\uparrow\uparrow n$ notation on the assumption that using $G(n)>TREE(3)$ might require an extremely large value for $n$.

I found this [How large is TREE(3)?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93828/how-large-is-tree3) post on [mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/), which should be useful in putting a lower bounds on the answer to this question, but I'm still trying to understand the post on mathoverflow.  A partial answer with the lower bounds answer would also be appreciated!

I also found this related mathstack question giving a [lower bound for Kruskal's weak tree function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2893373/lower-bound-for-kruskals-weak-tree-function), which along with the [wikipedia TREE(3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_tree_theorem) article may give a lower bounds for this answer.

**EDIT:** The [Fast-growing hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy) along with [another Tree(n) mathstack](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950116/where-does-treen-sit-on-the-fast-growing-hierarchy) question provides a possible answer.  Here is the Goodstein sequence written exactly in terms of the fast growing hierarchy; hopefully my notation here is correct:

- $G(4)=f_3(3)-2$
- $G(8)=f_{\omega+1}(3)-2$
- $G(16)=f_{\omega^\omega}(3)-2$
- $G(2\uparrow\uparrow n) = f_{\omega\uparrow\uparrow(n-1)}(3)-2$

The [mathoverflow Tree3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93828/how-large-is-tree3) link gives this inequality:

TREE(3) $\geq H_{\vartheta (\Omega^{\omega}, 0)}(n(4))$

Based on the links, the Fast-growing hierachy can be written in term's of Hardy's H function but I don't understand the $\Omega^\omega$ notation term in the inequality.  The implication seems to be that *more * layers of diagonalization are required and perhaps $TREE(3) > G(2\uparrow \uparrow n)$ for any value of n that could possibly be written down!

Comment: It's worth trying the Googology Wiki.

Comment: Thanks for the link Benjamin!  On the one hand, it appears that this  is a very difficult question, yet on the other hand, Friedman writes, "Also, numbers derived from Goodstein sequences or Paris/Harrington Ramsey theory, although bigger than n(4), are also completely UNNOTICEABLE in comparison to TREE[3]."  So perhaps $G(2\uparrow\uparrow n)<TREE(3)$ for any value of n that we could hope to write down as a decimal integer ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***How large a value of n would be required*** so that
> $G(2\uparrow\uparrow n)>TREE(3)$?

> perhaps $TREE(3) > G(2\uparrow \uparrow n)$ for any value of n that could possibly be written down!

Yes, and this should not be surprising! Using the fast-growing hierarchy with fundamental sequences defined as in the reference below at Footnote(2), we have, for all $n\gt 2,$
$$G(2\uparrow\uparrow n) = f_{\omega\uparrow\uparrow(n-1)}(3)-2 \lt f_{\epsilon_0}(n)$$

whereas$^\dagger$

$$TREE(3) \gt f_{\epsilon_0+1}(k) 
$$
where $k$ is [Graham's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number#Definition). (Using $\epsilon_0+1$ here is an *extremely* conservative choice.)

If $n^*$ denotes the least $n$ s.t. $G(2\uparrow\uparrow n)>TREE(3),$ then $n^*$ must be greater than the least $n$ s.t.
$$f_{\epsilon_0}(n)\gt f_{\epsilon_0+1}(k)=f_{\epsilon_0}^{k}(k),
$$
i.e., $$n^* \gt f_{\epsilon_0}^{k-1}(k).$$

The decimal digits of Graham's number $k$ are already impossible to "write down", let alone doing so for the digits of $\underbrace{f_{\epsilon_0}(f_{\epsilon_0}(\dots f_{\epsilon_0}(k)\dots ))}_{k-1 \text{ applications of } f_{\epsilon_0}}.$

**NB**: The cited references prove (rigorously) that $TREE(3) > f_{\Gamma_0}(k).$ Thus $f_{\epsilon_0}(n^*)\gt f_{\Gamma_0}(k),$ from which we could derive much stronger results of the form $n^*>f_{\epsilon_0}^{-1}f_{\Gamma_0}(k);$ but nothing stronger than our very weak bound is needed to answer your question.

---

$^\dagger$ This **extremely** weak lower bound is proved by combining the following two facts that are established at the cited links:

(1) https://mathoverflow.net/a/95588/20307:
$$TREE(3) \gt tree(n(4))\gt tree(5)$$

(2) https://recursion-theory.blogspot.com/2020/05/lower-bounds-for-tree4-and-tree5.html:
$$tree(5) > f_{\Gamma_0}(\text{Graham's number}) \gt f_{\epsilon_0+1}(\text{Graham's number}) $$

Comment: Are there any differences in the definitions of the Hardy fast growing hierarchy for the goodstein function and for the Tree function that would make it difficult to prove:  $$TREE(3) \ge H_{\vartheta (\Omega^{\omega}, 0)}(k) \gg f_{\epsilon_0+1}(k) 
$$
In the https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/TREE_sequence footnote 3 says that estimates for a lower bounds of TREE(3) cannot be made rigorous.

Comment: @SheldonL  I prefer to answer your question (the one I quoted) without addressing any controversy about the lower bound $H_{\vartheta (\Omega^{\omega}, 0)}(n(4)).$ Thus, I've edited my answer to avoid using that lower bound altogether.

Comment: The equations are brilliant, and I especially like the approach in $G(2\uparrow\uparrow 
 n)$ in terms of $f_{\epsilon_0(n-1)}-2$ and then showing that Tree(3) is at least $f_{\epsilon_0+1}$.  Thanks!